# DefaultIfEmpty doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, linq, arrays, defaultifempty

Why is  array still null after queried by DefaultIfEmpty ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program[] array = new Program[5];
        Program[] query = array.DefaultIfEmpty(new Program()).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the reason for `Program` to be a static class.

Comment: @John: What, to make it hard to demonstrate the problem? I see no problem with this sample code using a non-static class as an entry point.

Comment: @Jon: that was meant, in part, as a joke. In part it was an expression of horror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array isn't empty - it's got 5 elements, each of which has a null value.

Note that `array` itself *isn't* null - and neither is `query`. But each *element* of them is null.

A *truly* empty array would have 0 elements:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program[] array = new Program[0];
        Program[] query = array.DefaultIfEmpty(new Program()).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to filter null elements while you're copying the array:

```
Program[] query = array.Where(x => x != null)
                       .DefaultIfEmpty(new Program())
                       .ToArray();
```

EDIT: Perhaps you misunderstood the purpose of `DefaultIfEmpty`? This works on the whole *sequence*, not on an individual element basis. The idea isn't to replace null elements with a default value; it's to make sure that the result *sequence* is never empty. If you want to do a simple "replace null with a new value" you can do:

```
Program[] query = array.Select(x => x ?? new Program())
                       .ToArray();
```

Note that this will create a new value of `Program` for each null element; if you only want to create a single instance of `Program` and use multiple references to that, one for each originally null element, you could do this:

```
Program defaultValue = new Program();
Program[] query = array.Select(x => x ?? defaultValue)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Right i wanted to say my Array elements instead of array

Comment: Expected none-null elements after query but still all null

Comment: @Freshblood: Why would you only expect non-null elements? You haven't *asked* for only non-null elements, you've just said "if the input sequence has no elements, provide a default one in the result sequence". See my edit for how to get only non-null elements.

Comment: I am trying to assign default value for them if they empty(null) but this code doesn't provide it to me

Comment: @Freshblood: Basically you've misunderstood the purpose of the DefaultIfEmpty method. Read the docs carefully, and the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: Still i am reading documantation for understand purpose of DefaultIfEmpty :)

Comment: Purpose of my sample code wasn't assign none-null values to array elements.Purpose was understand purpose of DefaultIfEmpty.Already i could assign them default values as u gave some samples to me .

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty returns his input value  If returning Array has no elements.Am i right ?

Comment: @Freshblood: It always returns a sequence. If the original sequence is empty, the result sequence contains the default value (either the type's default value, or the one specified as an argument). If the original sequence *isn't* empty, the result sequence contains the same elements as the original sequence.

Comment: Ah sequence is mean a collection which contains elements ... so i understand it just returns collection which contains one element if DefualtIfEmpty works .

Comment: Finally i have understood. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just want:

```
var query = Array.ConvertAll(array, item => item ?? new Program());
```